# How can I specify the background color for matching search results?

Tags: colors, highlighting, isearch

When I incrementally search for a phrase with <kbd>C-S</kbd>, emacs usually highlights *all* matching results visible in the buffer by giving them a different background color. However, my current theme apparently uses the same background color as the normal background color, meaning I can't see the difference.

How can I specify a background color for matching search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `lazy-highlight` face.

You didn't mention what color your background is, so modify the below as needed:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :background "green")
```

Similarly, you can set the foreground color with:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black")
```

And you can combine the two with:

```el
(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black" :background "green")
```

---

To figure out what face needed to be modified, I did `M-x describe-char` as described in [this answer](//emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22449/675). I first had to set `lazy-highlight-cleanup` to `nil` so that the selection wasn't cleared when exiting the isearch.

Comment: Perfect. I also ended up setting the foreground color with `(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black")`

Comment: @Ben: You can also combine the two; see my updated answer.

Comment: I have tried `(set-face-attribute 'lazy-highlight nil :foreground "black" :background "green")` which does not change the selected main word on the `isearch`